# Orion Context Provider query multiple entities

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Tax information system contains all Tax information regarding every citizen in the city.

Following FIWARE principles, seems it might make sense Consumers query Orion about entity(citizen) tax information, and the request being forwarded to Context Provider (ie:TaxInformationSystem).

`Query citizen X tax information -> Orion -> TaxInformationSystem_CP`

According to [documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html), Context Providers can register themselves as source for specific attributes. This, for example, could make this work:

`http://{{orion}}/v2/entities/urn:citizenID/attrs/name/tax`

However, this **seems** to require every citizen to be registered as an entity, so tax information system should register *multiple times* (one per citizen). (And residenceInformationSystem, and healthInformationSystem, and...)

```
"entities": [
  {
    "id" : "citizenID",      //one per citizen ???
    "type": "taxInformation"
  }
],
```

and that seems, at least, a lot of unnecessary/superfluous work.

After reading a bit more, [**seems any workaround is not yet implemented/supported**](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/ngsiv2_implementation_notes/index.html#registrations)

- Seems I can't use query parameters `http://{{orion}}/v2/entities/tax?citizen=X`, as they [aren't forwarded to CP](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2282)
- Seems I can't query *any* citizen tax `http://{{orion}}/v2/entities/X/tax` if the entity hasn't be explicitly created first
- Seems I can't set *idPattern* (currently only .* supported), as it would return **all citizens** tax, as Broker is not forwarding requests filters neither *entity* to CP
- Neither *typePattern*

> (IIUC, *isPattern* seems now deprecated in favour of idPattern/typePattern)

**Am I doing something wrong? Is registering once *per citizen* the only way to go?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm fully understanding you case...

You could do a registration for all citizen like this one:

```
{
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": "taxInformation"
      }
    ],
    "attrs": [
      ...
  },
  "provider": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://thetaxsystem.com"
    }
  }
}
```

So if you want to get tax information of an specific citizen you could do something like this at the CB:

```
GET /v2/entities/1234567H?type=taxInformation
```

and that registration would cause the request sent to the tax system as Context Provider.

**EDIT:** there is an issue at Context Broker ([this one](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3463)) which is precluding this case to work. In particular, second case:

> regR = `.*`, query = 'E', attrs = {null}

**EDIT2:** the above case has been solved in Orion Context Broker. It is now available in master branch (`:latest` tag in dockerhub) and will be included in the next Orion Context Broker release (3.1.0).

Comment: Isn't that forwarding the request to CP /op/query like: `[ { idPattern: '.*', type: 'taxInformation' } ]` ?. Wouldn't that retrieve ALL citizen tax information?

Comment: I don't think so. The request that is forwarded is the same that the client sends (i.e. for entity id `1234567H`). However it would be great if you could test it and tell us ;)

Comment: Already tested...CP doesn't seem to receive entity, Neihter on query, headers and body.

Comment: Which Orion Context Broker version are you using, i.e. the first line in the output of `contextBroker --version`?

Comment: The one bundled on tutorials:
"version": "3.0.0",
"uptime": "1 d, 0 h, 20 m, 26 s",
"git_hash": "d6f8f4c6c766a9093527027f0a4b3f906e7f04c4",
"compile_time": "Mon Apr 12 14:48:44 UTC 2021",
"compiled_by": "root",
"compiled_in": "f307ca0746f5",
"release_date": "Mon Apr 12 14:48:44 UTC 2021",
"machine": "x86_64",
"doc": "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/en/3.0.0/",

Comment: After having a closer look, it seem that an issue in CB (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3463) is precluding to work as expected.

Comment: With regards to FIWARE as a whole, others should tell ;) With regards to the specific issue we are discussing here in this question post, check EDIT2 in my answer above.

Comment: after 3.1.0 release, context provider is receiving .* within request body, hence not being able to identify which entity is being requested. is this the desired operation?
@fgalan

Comment: I'd need more detail on the particular case. Please open an issue at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new with the detail of the requests you are doing at CB  (curl commands prefereable) and the result you get in 3.1.0 and in 3.0.0 so we can have a look.

Comment: ...anyway, as Perrolobo's answer says, CPr funcionality can be problematic. We don't recommend to use it in real use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In FIWARE, and in every system or platform, there are features more used and mature and others more experimental and dizzy. The more the real use cases and the real customers ask for some features (and moreover uses at real life and real deployments) they will get more consolidated, proved and extended. That's not the case for registrations, complex federation scenarios are not in current state of the art. I agree that they enable some really interesting experimental use cases, but in real deployments federation scenarios add an extra level of complexity making them undesirable at this stage.